# Can github create a project based off of individual repo projects?

Tags: github, kanban, github-projects

I want to create a higher level (orginization) project that contains the cards from multiple individual repositories projects.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/209 you might be looking for an **organisation** as higher level entity:

> However, the search interface in "Add cards" is limited to the current organization.

#### References

- https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/admin/user-management/creating-organizations
- https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-project-board#creating-an-organization-wide-project-board